# How to insert/implement JQuery Rotating Tab code into the HTML page

Tags: jquery, html

I have tabs on left hand side of my HTML which on hover shows images.
Now I want my tabs to display image automatically without cursor movement.

I am using jquery for the first time plz explain what is roottexts in this code.
All I know is syntax.  Where and how to insert in the code is unknown.

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
   $("#roottexts").tabs().tabs("rotate",5000, true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

roottexts is an id of an element in your html that should contain the tabs

you should really read up a bit more on jquery. There are plenty of tutorials available and the http://api.jquery.com page will be your best friend here. It's always worth trying to get some understanding the just copying and pasting

Comment: I am still unable to apply this rotate function.And Thanks for the link but i din get any rotate function.

Comment: like if id=abc and div = tab then how to refer on this tab

Comment: if the id is abc you would use $('#abc').tabs({"rotate", 5000, true});

Is this actually the jqueryui you are using? Are you able to set-up an example on jsfiddle.net as it will make it easier for people to help you